# dictionaries key/value in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to build a application that takes input from the user and encodes it and displays it back to the user.every letter in the user input should be replaced by a different letter in the output. This is used with dictionary's key/value. In my code it will only work with one letter, if anymore letters are entered then one it breaks. any ideas would be greatly appreciated to able to type in a word in the input and it prints out the opposite letters as a word in the output.

```
def getInput():

    userInput = input("Enter String to encode: ")
    return userInput

def displayOutput(userInput, encoding ):

    matchFound = False
    for key in encoding:
        if (key == userInput):
            print("Encoded message", encoding[key])
            matchFound = True
            break


    if matchFound == False:
        print("***Error*** No Match Found!")

def main():

    encoding ={"a": "b", "b": "c", "c": "d", "d": "e", "e": "f", "f": "g", "g": "h", "h": "i", "i": "j", "j": "k", "k": "l", "l": "m", "m": "n", "n": "o", "o": "p", "p": "q", "q": "r", "r": "s", "s": "t", "t": "u", "u": "v", "v": "w", "w": "x", "x": "y", "y": "z", "z": "a", " ": "-"}


    userInput = getInput()
    displayOutput(userInput, encoding)


main()
```

Comment: Can you be more detailed than "it breaks"?

Comment: You need to loop over the characters in the input string.

Comment: Also, why not `if user_input in encoding` and avoid that `for key in encoding` loop?

Comment: Are you just trying to encode the entire `userInput` string to see if there is a match?

Comment: here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Enter string to encode: intro to programming with python
Encoded message: jousp-up-qsphsbnnjoh-xjui-qzuipo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, the following approach could work for you. Try to encode, if there isn't a value entry, then handle the no existing encoding found situation.

```
def encode(s, encoding):
    try:
        return ''.join(encoding[character] for character in s)
    except KeyError:
        print "Encoding not found."
```

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> encoding = {"a": "b", "b": "c", "c": "d", "d": "e", "e": "f", "f": "g", "g": "h", "h": "i", "i": "j", "j": "k", "k": "l", "l": "m", "m": "n", "n": "o", "o": "p", "p": "q", "q": "r", "r": "s", "s": "t", "t": "u", "u": "v", "v": "w", "w": "x", "x": "y", "y": "z", "z": "a", " ": "-"}
>>> encode("helloworld", encoding)    
ifmmpxpsme
>>> encode("HelloWorld", encoding) 
Encoding not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing elements of your encoding to the whole of `userInput`; you need to process each character of it individually.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to figure out and I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: Do you know how to access each character of `userInput`?

Comment: unfortunately I do not. do you have an example maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing the entire input string to the encoding keys, you should be iterating through the characters of the userInput string.  Something like:

```
encodedString = ""

for inputChar in userInput:
    if ( inputChar in encoding ):
        encodedChar = encoding[inputChar]
        encodedString = encodedString + encoding[inputChar]
    else:
        encodedString = encodedString + inputChar
```

(Not tested... just typed off the top of my head, so may not actually run.)

This solution assumes that you want an output string (encodedString) and that for characters not in the encoding, you would just use the input character.  Not sure if that's what you really want or not.

EDIT:  If you want it to only work for input characters that are in the encoding, then mrdomoboto's solution is more efficient and more compact.

Comment: What seems to be presumably Java, in a Python tagged question, interesting choice.

Comment: Yes, sorry... fixed that now I think.